# How to replace dynamic string values in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

In my application requirement are to replace text with line break.
Mine code is

```
pageText = pageText.Replace("<td style=\"width:23.0769230769231%;\">", "<br>");
```

Here width value is dynamic which is different for different pdf pages.
How to replace this whole string with line break by using string.Replace or using Regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a regex which will replace the string: `"<td style=\"width:X;\">"` with `"<br>"` where X is any number?

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, "<td style=\"width:\\d+\\.?\\d*%;\">", "<br>"));
```

.NET fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/30QCRP

Comment: @Tokn I wanted to test some date stuff earlier and typed dotnetfiddle into Google. I assumed it would be created eventually. I was RIGHT! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  string pattern = "<(.*?)>";
  string replacement = "<br>";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Or yo could be more specific if you start with this:

```
string pattern = "<td style=(.*?)>";
```